# R shiny : if with checkboxGroupInput

Tags: r, shiny

I have this code in my Server but the value NB_ind does not display. It displays only the message if boxes are checked, and if I uncheck boxes, the message "Number of persons who did not answer this question"" does not appear at all.

Do you see why ? Thanks a lot.

This my Ui.R :

```
checkboxGroupInput("skin", label = "Skin color", choices = list
("01. White" = "1", "02. Black" = "2", "03. Yellow" = "3",
 "04. Mixed" = "4")),

textOutput("ETH")
```

And my Server.R :

```
observeEvent(input$skin,{

if (is.null(input$skin)){NB_ind <- "  Number of persons who did not 
                                      answer this question"}
else {NB_ind <- "  Number of persons who have checked this/these 
                   box(es)"}

# Process for counting number of persons who answered or not the question
#selectionETH <- reactive({filter(filter(BI14, PC %in% input$dynamic &
#              ETH %in% paste(input$skin,collapse=""), AGER >= 
#              input$age[1] & AGER <= input$age[2]))   
#})

output$ETH <- renderText({NB_ind})   
})
```

Thank you very much for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a possible solution:

server.R (ui.R stays the same)

```
library(shiny)


    shinyServer(function(input, output) {

            NB_indRv <- reactive({
                    if (is.null(input$skin)){NB_ind <- "  Number of persons who did not 
                                          answer this question"}
                    else {NB_ind <- "  Number of persons who have checked this/these 
                    box(es)"}    
                    NB_ind
            })
                    output$ETH <- renderText(NB_indRv())
    })
```

Comment: Thank you so much Valter, it's not the first time you help me. Thank you for spending time in helping newbies. Have a very good day.

Comment: Glad it helped!